# Virtual Router & Android

Tags: windows-7, android, hotspot

I am looking for a way to share my laptop's internet connection with my android phone (Xperia L). I use "Virtual Router" for this. I am able to scan and recognize Virtual Router by phone but connection is not established

```
 hostname could not be found
 ip address could not be found
```

I am running "Windows 7 Enterprise" on laptop. Is there a way to share the connection?

Comment: Have you shared you Internet Connection? Have you tried static IP Configuration on phone?

Comment: When static ip then VR says "connected" but browser says "This webpage is not available" - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Comment: Have you shared you Internet Connection?

Comment: yes - connection shared - now seems android connected - but can't rezch internet

Answer (score 2):

I tried many approaches and programs to make my android device to connect to laptop's Virtual WiFi Wireless Hosted Network, including Connectify, the mentioned mHotspot and Virtual Router Manager (it was the only program which at least explained the problem in the form of stating `hostname could not be found` etc., the others simply didn't see any connecting devices) and also manual Windows 7 cmd (as described here http://www.oszone.net/10758/Virtual_Wi_Fi#01)

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Name key=8CharacterKey
>
> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

After that I tried cmd `ipconfig/renew` and `ipconfig/flushdns`, changed `Windows - Control Panel - Device Manager - Network Adapters - Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter - Properties - Power Management -` turn off `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` but also without any success in my case, though I've read others say it helped.

Solution:

1. Turned off the laptop's internet by turning off the router (it was only before first time I managed to establish connection, later it worked while internet was on - i.e. with both wifi-networks, "laptop's main" and "laptop's hotspot" on one physical laptop's wifi-adapter simultaneously).
2. (I suppose this step was crucial). Changed on laptop `Windows - Control Panel - Network and sharing center - Change adapter settings MyLaptopNetwork - Properties - Internet protocol version 4 - IP adress = 169.252.131.1, Mask = 255.255.0.0`.
   Then changed in android `Settings` - press long `MyLaptopNetwork` - `Modify network configuration` - tick `Show advanced options` - `IP Settings` = `Static`, `IP adress = 169.252.131.5, Gateway = 169.252.131.1, DNS 1 = 8.8.8.8`.
3. `Windows - Control Panel - Power Options - Change Plan Settings - Change Advanced Power Settings - Wireless Adapter Setings - Power Saving Mode -  Maximum Performance` (as described here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928152 though for completely another problem).

*(Need testing yet to be sure which step exactly helped, though I think the second one, as proposed by AEonAX, while the third is also not excessive as my HP Pavilion's wifi adapter, as I found on forums, tends to be rather week, nevertheless I really managed to solve the considered here problem.)*

Of course, I still had the second problem described in comments to the main question "now seems android connected - but can't rezch internet".

Solution for the second problem:

1. `Windows - Control Panel - Network and sharing center - Change advanced sharing settings - Home or Work` (my MyLaptopNetwork is "Work" while the main laptop's network for internet access in "Public") - `Turn on network discovery` and `Turn on file and printer sharing` - `Save changes`.

Now everythihg is ok and internet is shared to android device.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this program i use it all the time

> http://www.mhotspot.com/

mHotSpot is great and works on all internet devices even usb modems